# Inputs are not printing as expected

Tags: python, syntax, calculation

- #this program should allow a user to input their bodyweight and calculate how much they should be lifting based off of that number in
  terms of squat and bench.

  ```
  x = int(input("This program I made is to calculate how much you should be squatting. How much do you weight?: "))
  y = int(input("This program I made is to calculate how much you should be benching. How much do you weight?: "))  

  def squat(x):
      x = squat
      while squat < 165 and squat > 145:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 145-165 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 100-110 lbs.")
      if squat < 181 and squat > 166:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 166-181 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 110-120 lbs.")
      elif squat < 198 and squat > 182:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 182-198 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 120-125 lbs.")
      elif squat < 220 and squat > 199:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 199-220 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 125-130 lbs.")
      elif squat < 242 and squat > 200:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 200-242 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 130-135 lbs.")
      elif squat < 275 and squat > 242:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 242-275 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 135-140 lbs.")
      elif squat < 319 and squat > 243:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 243-319 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat 140-145 lbs.")
      else: squat > 320
      print("You have fallen into the range of 320+ lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to squat around 150 lbs.")

  def bench(y):
      y = bench
      while bench < 165 and bench > 148:
          print("You have fallen into the range of 148-165 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 110-120 lbs.")
          if bench < 181 and bench > 166:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 166-181 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 110-120 lbs.")
          elif bench < 198 and bench > 182:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 182-198 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 120-125 lbs.")
          elif bench < 220 and bench > 198:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 198-220 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 125-130 lbs.")
          elif bench < 242 and bench > 221:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 221-242 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 130-135 lbs.")
          elif bench < 275 and bench > 243:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 243-275 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 135-140 lbs.")
          elif bench < 319 and bench > 275:
              print("You have fallen into the range of 243-275 lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 140-145 lbs.")
          else: bench > 320
          print("You have fallen into the range of 320+ lbs. At this weightclass you should be able to bench 150+ lbs.")

      print(squat(x), bench(y))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem could be:
When checking ranges of numbers, make sure that you are not missing any numbers.
For example, you check "bench < 242 and bench > 221", and "bench < 220 and bench > 198", but what if bench was 220? None of the conditions are met.
It might be a good idea to use >= comparisons to make sure you are including your boundary numbers.

so changing to :

```
< 242 and bench >= 221
<= 220 and bench > 198
```

would make sure that all the numbers are accounted for. You'll have to do the same for each boundary number.